# Delete and move file to a directory in java

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to move a file from one directory to another using renameTo() in java, however renameTo doesnt work (doesnt rename and move the file).  Basically, I want to delete the file in one first with same file name, then copy a file from anoter directory to the same location where I deleted the file originally, then copy the new one with same name.

```
    //filePath = location of original file with file name appended. ex: C:\Dir\file.txt
    //tempPath = Location of file that I want to replace it to file file without the file name.  ex: C:\AnotherDir

    int pos = filePath.indexOf("C:\\Dir\\file.txt");
    //Parse out only the path, so just C:\\Dir
    String newFilePath = filePath.substring(0,pos-1);

    //I want to delete the original file
    File deletefile = new File(newFilePath,"file.txt");

    if (deletefile.exists()) {
        success = deletefile.delete();
    }


    //There is file already exists in the directory, but I am just appending .tmp at the end
    File newFile = new File(tempPath + "file.txt" + ".tmp");

    //Create original file again with same name.
    File oldFile = new File(newFilePath, "file.txt");

    success = oldFile.renameTo(newFile); // This doesnt work.
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what doesn't work? do you get an error message of any kind? does the program exit normally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes in the string literal: `"C:\\Dir\\file.txt"`. Or use `File.separator` to construct the path.

Additionally, ensure `newFile`'s path is constructed properly:

```
File newFile = new File(tempPath + File.separator + "file.txt" + ".tmp");
                               //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

as the commments in the posted code (`...ex: C:\AnotherDir`) indicate that `tempPath` has no trailing slash character.

Comment: Ah, when is Java going to get raw string support, even C++ has it now.

Comment: @Benj If you are to hardcode the strings you can use `c:/Dir/file.txt` directly

Comment: @OscarRyz true but there are other instances where raw strings are useful.  I like C#s @"\string\with\slash" or C++s R"\strings\".  Just look at the difference it makes to the readability of regex! I hated writing those in java with all the "\\d" etc constantly.

Comment: @Benk Agree, specially in the regex part

Answer (score 0):

I have moved files to the destination directory and after moving deleted those moved files from source folder, in three ways, and at last am using the 3rd approach in my project.

1st approach:

```
File folder = new File("SourceDirectory_Path");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    Files.move(Paths.get("SourceDirectory_Path"+listOfFiles[i].getName()), Paths.get("DestinationDerectory_Path"+listOfFiles[i].getName()));
    }
    System.out.println("SUCCESS");
```

2nd approach:

```
 Path sourceDir = Paths.get("SourceDirectory_Path");
    Path destinationDir = Paths.get("DestinationDerectory_Path");
      try(DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream =   Files.newDirectoryStream(sourceDir)){
        for (Path path : directoryStream) {
            File d1 = sourceDir.resolve(path.getFileName()).toFile();
             File d2 = destinationDir.resolve(path.getFileName()).toFile(); 
             File oldFile = path.toFile();
            if(oldFile.renameTo(d2)){
                System.out.println("Moved");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Not Moved");
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

3rd approach:

```
Path sourceDirectory= Paths.get(SOURCE_FILE_PATH);
            Path destinationDirectory = Paths.get(SOURCE_FILE_MOVE_PATH);
            try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(sourceDirectory)) {
                for (Path path : directoryStream) {                                    
                    Path dpath = destinationDirectory .resolve(path.getFileName());                                    
                    Files.move(path, dpath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();   
            }
```

Happy Coding !! :)